# How to transferring an array of main functions to a class?

Tags: c++, arrays, class

First of all, I made this class.

```cpp
class Matrix
{
public:
    double ele[4][4];
    int numOfRow;
    int numOfColumns;
public:
    Matrix() {
        numOfRow = 0;
        numOfColumns = 0;
        ele[4][4] = 0;
    }
    Matrix(double mat[][4], int Row, int Col) {
        numOfRow = Row;
        numOfColumns = Col;
        for (int i = 0; i < numOfRow; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; i < numOfColumns; j++) {
                ele[i][j] = mat[i][j];  
            }
        }
    }
    Matrix Add(Matrix m) {
        Matrix output;
        for (int i = 0; i < numOfRow; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < numOfColumns; j++) {
                output.ele[i][j] = ele[i][j] + m.ele[i][j];
            }
        }
        return output;
    }
    Matrix Subtract(Matrix m);
    Matrix Multiply(Matrix m);
    Matrix Transpose(void);
};
```

This is part of the main function. In this way, I'm going to bring up the values of the txt files that I've already made in `matA` and `matB` and replace them. It's just a process of putting numbers in.

```cpp
        double matA[4][4];
        for (int i = 0; i < RowA; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < ColA; j++) {
                fscanf(fpInput, "%lf", &matA[i][j]);
            }
        }
        double matB[4][4];
        for (int i = 0; i < RowB; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < ColB; j++) {
                fscanf(fpInput, "%lf", &matB[i][j]);
            }
        }
```

And we substitute `matrixA` and `matrixB` class objects, respectively.

```cpp
        Matrix matrixA(matA, RowA, ColA);
        Matrix matrixB(matB, RowB, ColB);
```

I tried substitute Value obtained by 'Add' function into class object called `matrixO`. but, The substituted values did not work smoothly. For example, if `matrixA` contains `(1, 2, 3)` in order and `matrixB` has `(4, 5, 6)`, then the 'add function' requires that the array of `matrixO` contains `(5, 7, 9)`, but it does not. The value of the `matrixO.ele` is not output at all.

```cpp
            Matrix matrixO = matrixA.Add(matrixB);
            for (int i = 0; i < RowA; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < ColA; j++) {
                    fprintf(fpOutput, "%lf ", matrixO.ele[i][j]);
                    printf("%lf", matrixO.ele[i][j]);
                }
                fprintf(fpOutput, "\n");
            }
```

In the Matrix constructor section, I changed it like this.

```
public:
    Matrix() {
        numOfRow = 0;
        numOfColumns = 0;
        ele[4][4] = ele[0][0];
    }
```

```
public:
    Matrix() {
        numOfRow = 0;
        numOfColumns = 0;
        ele[4][4] = {};
    }
```

But both of these cases are wrong. How do we solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning a value to your matrix out-of-bounds:

```
    ele[4][4] = 0;
```

The last element of `double ele[4][4];` is `ele[3][3];`

This is undefined behavior, so it makes no sense to analyze what happens after it.

You can 0-initialize your `Matrix` in its constructor like this:

```
Matrix(): ele(), numOfRow(), numOfColumns() {}
```

Comment: Do you mean that I can change this part of ```ele[4][4] = 0;``` to ```ele[3][3] = 0``` in the constructor? The value is output, but debugging only results in strange values.

Comment: @Keastmin No, that will only set ONE element to 0. Please see my updated answer